# Razor view template fails to parse in Azure with RazorEngine

Tags: c#, azure, razor, razorengine

I'm using the RazorEngine library (https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/) in a web application to parse razor view templates.

The following code should parse the template.

```
        try
        {
            var html = IoHelper.GetFileContent(template);
            html = Razor.Parse<TModel>(html, model);
            html = html.Replace("src=\"/", "src=\"" + Common.GetSiteUrl() + "/");
            html = html.Replace("href=\"/", "href=\"" + Common.GetSiteUrl() + "/");
            html = html.Replace("src='/", "src='" + Common.GetSiteUrl() + "/");
            html = html.Replace("href='/", "href='" + Common.GetSiteUrl() + "/");
            return html;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogError("PdfReportService RenderPdfHtml() Failed!", ex);
            return "";
        }
```

It works fine locally, fine on a Azure VPS, but when I deploy as an Azure web app, it fails to parse. I feel it hangs totally and don't even enter the catch... (hard to tell since I can't debug in production) Even tried with an updated RazorEngine version and an updated parse technique, but no success either.

What could be the difference in the Azure web app that makes the parse fail fail...

(I used the same database everywhere, so it's not that there is something wrong with the model passed to the razor view)

Comment: Can you try to strip the code and see if anything changes. I'm especially interested if it will run if you remove the first line with IoHelper. Change that th a hard coded strig, if this is possible.

Comment: It's indeed not the RazorEngine that fails.  It seems that var pdf.AddImageHtml(html); (an ABCpdf10 method) fails in Azure

Comment: It's not allowed to run external processes from within your Windows Azure Web app as this would pose a risk in the shared infrastructure.  So it's unable to call the Gecko layout engine...  Problem solved.